# How to import MaterialViewPager to eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-viewpager

I want to import this library: 
**https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager**

Any thing i have done,I couldn't import and make usage this project in my own project. I'm newbie!

How can i just import it to my project in eclipse?

Please tell me i have to copy which folder to my own project and how to use it?

I don't know i have to make a new library or just copy file in my own project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Download the library as a zip
Extract it
Go to 
materialviewpager/src/main

You will see java and res folder
Open the java folder you will see com folder, copy it to your apps src folder

Open the res folder, dont copy it yet.
Go to values folder
rename the xml files inside it to this
anything_XMLFILENAME.xml just to avoid any copying conflicts

now copy the contents of res folder to your app's res folder.

You will have some errors in library's class files because you need to organize the imports first.

And viola you now have the library :D